# When react calculator with voice recognition deployed using npm run dev command a blank page is shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I tried to build a calculator app with voice recognition using chat gpt in following stack :react ,typescript and vite js .When I deployed with the command`npm run dev` the website was showing a white blank page.Can you please help me to build the website.I coded this in visual studio
main.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import Calculator from "./Component/Calculator";
import "./styles/calculator.css";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Calculator />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Calculator.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from "react-speech-recognition";
import "../styles/calculator.css";
function Calculator() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState("");

  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setResult(result.concat(e.currentTarget.name));
  };

  const clear = () => {
    setResult("");
  };

  const backspace = () => {
    setResult(result.slice(0, -1));
  };

  function evaluateExpression(expression: string): string {
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-new-func
      const result = Function(`"use strict"; return (${expression})`)();
      return result.toString();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return "Error";
    }
  }

  const calculate = () => {
    try {
      let num: number = 0; 
      const score= num.toString(); 
      const result = evaluateExpression(score);
      setResult(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setResult("Error");
    }
  };

  const { resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition();

  const handleVoiceRecognition = () => {
    if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
      console.log("Your browser does not support speech recognition");
      return;
    }

    SpeechRecognition.startListening({
      continuous: true,
      language: "en-US",
    });
  };

  const stopVoiceRecognition = () => {
    SpeechRecognition.stopListening();
    resetTranscript();
    calculate();
  };
  return (
    <div className="calculator">
    <input type="text" value={result} />
    <div className="keypad">
    <button className="operator" onClick={clear}>
    AC
    </button>
    <button className="operator" onClick={backspace}>
    C
    </button>
    <button className="operator" name="+" onClick={handleClick}>
    +
    </button>
    <button name="7" onClick={handleClick}>
    7
    </button>
    <button name="8" onClick={handleClick}>
    8
    </button>
    <button name="9" onClick={handleClick}>
    9
    </button>
    <button className="operator" name="-" onClick={handleClick}>
    -
    </button>
    <button name="4" onClick={handleClick}>
    4
    </button>
    <button name="5" onClick={handleClick}>
    5
    </button>
    <button name="6" onClick={handleClick}>
    6
    </button>
    <button className="operator" name="*" onClick={handleClick}>
    x
    </button>
    <button name="1" onClick={handleClick}>
    1
    </button>
    <button name="2" onClick={handleClick}>
    2
    </button>
    <button name="3" onClick={handleClick}>
    3
    </button>
    <button className="operator" name="/" onClick={handleClick}>
    ÷
    </button>
    <button name="." onClick={handleClick}>
    .
    </button>
    <button name="0" onClick={handleClick}>
    0
    </button>
    <button className="operator" onClick={calculate}>
    =
    </button>
    <button className="operator" onClick={handleVoiceRecognition}>
    
    </button>
    <button className="operator" onClick={stopVoiceRecognition}>
    
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
    }
    export default Calculator;
```

calculator.css

```
.calculator {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  
  .calculator input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: right;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  
  .keypad {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
  }
  
  button {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  button:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .operator {
    background-color: #ff8c00;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .operator:hover {
    background-color: #f60;
  }
```

Comment: What's in the console of your DevTools?